# Wrong GPS coordinates

Tags: android, android-location

Sometimes I get wrong GPS coordinates. They violate my route and calculation of distance.
How to get rid of them?

I use only GPS provider

```
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
        1000, 0, gpsLocationListener);
```

[image]

Comment: You will have to post your Location android code.

Comment: I believe, sometimes you are getting GPS co-ordinates from your network provider.

Comment: In your wrong GPS coordinates accuracy will be very big . you can check your accuracy of this GPS coordinates if accuracy > 300 -> don't use this point.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you get satellite signals reflections from buildings (like a mirror), meaning that the actual location is with an offset with the reflection.

The best method I found to avoid such cases is to check the consistency of the locations and filter out the outlaws.
You should probably check computers geometry codes about such problems.